# AWS, page is unable to save to file system

Tags: c#, asp.net, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I'm using the following code to save to the server.  The page is just uploding an image to a folder.  It works fine on my local host.  But when i upload the project to Amazon Web Services using Elastic Beanstalk, it gives an error.

```
 string fileName = FileUpload1.FileName;
 FileUpload1.SaveAs(Server.MapPath("~/Paperwork/" + lblcompid.Text + "-" + ListBox1.SelectedValue + "-paperworkfile_1_.png"));
```

> Server Error in '/' Application.
>
> Access to the path
>   'C:\inetpub\wwwroot\Paperwork\20045-11022-paperworkfile_1_.png' is
>   denied.
>
> Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of
>   the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more
>   information about the error and where it originated in the code.
>
> Exception Details: System.UnauthorizedAccessException: Access to the
>   path 'C:\inetpub\wwwroot\Paperwork\20045-11022-paperworkfile_1_.png'
>   is denied.
>
> ASP.NET is not authorized to access the requested resource. Consider
>   granting access rights to the resource to the ASP.NET request
>   identity. ASP.NET has a base process identity (typically
>   {MACHINE}\ASPNET on IIS 5 or Network Service on IIS 6 and IIS 7, and
>   the configured application pool identity on IIS 7.5) that is used if
>   the application is not impersonating. If the application is
>   impersonating via , the identity will be
>   the anonymous user (typically IUSR_MACHINENAME) or the authenticated
>   request user.
>
> To grant ASP.NET access to a file, right-click the file in File
>   Explorer, choose "Properties" and select the Security tab. Click "Add"
>   to add the appropriate user or group. Highlight the ASP.NET account,
>   and check the boxes for the desired access.

I know I need to do something with permissions, but have no idea what.  Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Resolved. Had to remote into the virtual server.  Then used command line to change the permissions to that folder.

icacls "c:\work" /grant Everyone:(OI)(CI)F